# Adding two values to a key in a HashMap in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, key

I am using a file that consists of:

`"word","wordtype","definition"`

`"Base","n.","The lower part of a robe or petticoat."`

`"Base","n.","An apron."`

The output is as follows:

`key: "base" value: ["word""wordtype""definition", "Base""n.""The lower part of a robe or petticoat.", "Base""n.""An apron."]
key: "word" value: ["word""wordtype""definition", "Base""n.""The lower part of a robe or petticoat.", "Base""n.""An apron."]`

Desired outcome:

`key: "base" value: [ "Base""n.""The lower part of a robe or petticoat.", "Base""n.""An apron."]
key: "word" value: ["word""wordtype""definition"]`

Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));

    String line = null;

    TreeMap<String, List<String>> def = new TreeMap<String, List<String>>();
    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String []parts =line.split(",");
                String key = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++){
                    key = parts[0];
                }

                values.add(parts[0] + parts[1] + parts[2]);
                def.put(key.toLowerCase(), values);

            }
```

Comment: For starters: `key = parts[0]` shouldn't be in a loop; `values` should be a new variable defined inside your while loop, and you should add each part you want added to the values list one at a time, not concatenating them together with +.

Comment: You can't use a Map for this.  One `key` must correspond to a single (or no) `value`.  If you want _similar_ functionality; you could use a `List<Map.Entry<String, String>>`.

Answer (score 1):

A `Map` cannot work as you request.  Any `key` can only be mapped to a single `value`.

If you want something *akin* to what you're doing, but where you can have multiple `values` for a given `key`, you could do something like:

```
List<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> def = new ArrayList<>();

Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry = new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(key, list);
def.add(entry);
```

Then iterate through your `def`:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : def) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Key: %s.  Values: %s",
            entry.getKey(),
            Arrays.toString(entry.getValue().toArray())));
}
```

Edit:

For your comment: If you want that, you can always roll your own type to store in the `Map` (or `List` if you still need duplicate keys):

```
class WordDescription {
    final String wordType;
    final String definition;

    WordDescription(String wordType, String definition) {
        this.wordType = wordType;
        definition = definition;
    }

    String getWordType() {
        return wordType;
    }

    String getDefinition() {
        return definition;
    }
}
```

And use that in a `List<Map.Entry<String, WordDescription>>`.  You can make `wordType` an `enum` if there's a pre-defined set of them (adjective, noun, etc.).

Comment: Thanks, ideally I want the key as the word, and value as the key wordtype and definition, but you cant have duplicate keys in maps

Comment: @b.d Edited answer to give further help to what you're looking for.

Comment: His edited response is really what you want here.  You want to store String->YourCustomObject.  Personally I'd add the actual word to your WordDescription object.  While you may think it is duplicative because it's already the key to your map you'd end up getting better resuability & encapsulation out of the object in the future.  Say you return a WordDescription and it gets passed to another part of your program or stored in another data structure; if you lose the map key, you no longer have any context about what word your object represents.

Comment: @dev.glitch Ya I think that is exactly what I need,Thanks